# Mac OS El Capitan (10.11) not able to connect to WIFI(WPA 2 Enterprise)

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have upgraded my MacBook Pro OS to 10.11 (El Capitan), since then its not able to connect to WIFI (WPA2 Enterprise) of our organisation. It is getting authenticated via EAP-PEAP but after that its not able to get IP address. It says No Ip Address while our IP pool is free as shown in [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aj7g5wcqphmkxvy/Screen_Shot_2015-07-02_at_1_00_40_PM.png?dl=0).
￼

I did try to troubleshoot by

1. Removing and adding WIFI interface.
2. Clearing the entire network cache.
3. Removed and added DNS servers.
4. Removed keychain entry of WIFI password.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. I think I found the answer in the release notes.

From the El Capitan Beta 4 release notes:

```
When negotiating a TLS/SSL connection with Diffie-Hellman key exchange, 
OS X El Capitan requires a 1024-bit group or larger.
OS X El Capitan will not connect to a server that allows negotiation with a 512-bit or smaller group.
These connections include:
        ⁃   Secure Web (HTTPS)
        ⁃   Enterprise Wi-Fi (802.1X)
        ⁃   Secure e-mail (IMAP, POP, SMTP)
        ⁃   Printing servers (IPPS)
```

iOS 9 also has the same issue and the same note in the release notes for it.

Comment: Thats correct but we will have to find some alternative solution.

Comment: The problem is that this is listed as a "note" and not a "known issue"/bug. Hopefully someone does have the answer though because my only option now is to talk to the IT department at my school and tell them about this situation.

Comment: Are there any news regarding this?

Comment: Well, the only way I have to test this is at school and I noticed that about a month ago, it started working again on both iOS and OS X and I think that was around the time I had upgraded both to the latest beta of that time. However, I still think it has this note in the release notes and the change may simply be due to upgrading the WiFi security, but I can't say for certain. It might be annoying but maybe its a good way to pressure companies/organizations into tightening network security to everyone's benefit using the network.